# haproxy shows a lot of ssl handshake failures and still loads the page

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, haproxy, self-signed-certificate

I am using HAproxy as my on-prem load balancer to my Kubernetes cluster. Here is the cfg file:

```
global
  chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
  pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
  maxconn     40000
  user        haproxy
  group       haproxy
  daemon
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
  log stdout local0  info
defaults
mode tcp
  log global
  option                  httplog
  retries                 3
  timeout http-request    50s
  timeout queue           1m
  timeout connect         1m
  timeout client          1m
  timeout server          1m
  timeout http-keep-alive 50s
  timeout check           10s
  maxconn                 1000
frontend https_front
  mode http
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxy.pem ca-file /etc/haproxy/haproxy.crt verify optional
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  acl sadmin path_beg /sadmin
  use_backend sadmin_server if sadmin
  default_backend sadmin_server
backend sadmin_server
  balance roundrobin
  mode http
  server node1 staging-node1:30000 check
  server node2 staging-node2:30000 check
  server node3 staging-node3:30000 check
  server node4 staging-node4:30000 check
```

I am using a self signed certificate which has been generated using the traditional openssl commands.

However, while connecting to the website, even though the pages load fine I keep seeing loads of below error:

```
<134>Oct 18 20:14:14 haproxy[6]: 10.118.108.170:51249 [18/Oct/2019:20:14:14.172] https_front/1: SSL handshake failure
<134>Oct 18 20:14:14 haproxy[6]: 10.118.108.170:51245 [18/Oct/2019:20:14:14.172] https_front/1: SSL handshake failure
<134>Oct 18 20:14:14 haproxy[6]: 10.118.108.170:51247 [18/Oct/2019:20:14:14.172] https_front/1: SSL handshake failure
<134>Oct 18 20:14:14 haproxy[6]: 10.118.108.170:51246 [18/Oct/2019:20:14:14.172] https_front/1: SSL handshake failure
```

- I have maxed out the connection parameters.
- I tried to load the certificate in the browser as well.
- Have tried the option verified optional & none.

But can't figure out the reason for these errors ?

PS: I have read the pages [Haproxy ssl redirect handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318597/haproxy-ssl-redirect-handshake-failure) and [How to track down "Connection timout during SSL handshake" and "Connection closed during ssl handshake" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512247/how-to-track-down-connection-timout-during-ssl-handshake-and-connection-close) and can't find the solution yet.

Comment: I've seen such behavior with Chrome: when an exception was added for a self-signed certificate (instead of importing it as trusted) it seems to connect first, realize that it is not trusted, abort the handshake and then try again while being now aware of the exception. Also I don't know about all your clients - but if the certificate is self-signed many will likely abort the handshake once they realize that it is not a trusted certificate.

Comment: I guess this was the issue! with self signed certs and firefox I dont see the errors at all. Now I have anyways switched to a CA signed certificate and chrome doesnt complain at all. Thank you!